# VerifyTrustFailed for C:\Windows\system32\WdfCoInstaller01011.dll

Tags: certificate, usb, wdk, signtool, inf

from setupapi.dev.log

*!    sig:                     VerifyTrustFailed for C:\Windows\system32\WinUsbCoInstaller2.dll.*

*!    sig:                     Error 0x800b0109: A certificate chain processed, but terminated in a root certificate which is not trusted by the trust provider.*

*!    sig:                     VerifyTrustFailed for C:\Windows\system32\WdfCoInstaller01011.dll.*

*!    sig:                     Error 0x800b0109: A certificate chain processed, but terminated in a root certificate which is not trusted by the trust provider.*

"signtool verify /pa WinUsbCoInstaller2.dll" returns "successfully Verified"

WinUSB loads and there are no errors in Device Manager.  But, this is kind of disturbing considering that WinUsbCoInstaller2.dll and WdfCoInstaller01011.dll are part of Windows Driver Kit 10 redistributables.

TIA for your help!

Comment: It would be nice if you could say what you're trying to achieve but I guess you are developing a Windows driver that uses WinUSB.  Have you considered taking the WinUSB binaries out of your driver?  WinUSB comes with Windows Vista and later so you don't need to redistribute binaries to use it, you just need an INF file and signed CAT file.

Comment: Yes, trying to connect our device to WinUSB.  according to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/usbcon/winusb-installation#howto

To use WinUSB as the device's function driver, you create a driver package. The driver package must contain these files:

- WinUSB co-installer (Winusbcoinstaller.dll)
- KMDF co-installer (WdfcoinstallerXXX.dll)
- An .inf file that installs Winusb.sys as the device's function driver. 
- A signed catalog file for the package. This file is required to install WinUSB on x64 versions of Windows starting with Vista.

Comment: The signed catalog file is indeed needed on modern versions of Windows, but those large DLLs are not needed.  You can remove those files from your driver and remove the references to them in the INF file.  I've distributed several products for my company taking advantage of this.  You can see an example here: https://github.com/pololu/pololu-tic-software/tree/master/drivers

Comment: If you go to the link below and look at the table, and read the footnotes, it only says the WinUSB co-installer is needed for Windows XP:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/usbcon/winusb  That's because, like I said, WinUSB is already installed on Windows Vista and later.

Comment: Sorry, still confused. Not installing on Windows XP.  If you look farther down from your link you will find my link which says we need to include KMDF co-installer.  Regardless, both DLL's are flagged with certificate error.